# Pasar Parametros a la configuración de menú (\config\adminlte.php) Laravel 8

Tags: menu

Comunidad.

```
Necesito de su gran ayuda y aporte, estoy tratando de configurara mi menú en la barra lateral izquierda de la plantilla adminlte con laravel 8, solo he logrdo colocar las opciones pero no logro pasar el id dimanico para que funcionen las opciones del menú. 

En detalle, tengo una tabla Finca donde se registran cada una de las fincas que estaran en el sistema y  el  menú lateral debe recibir el id de la finca para que muestre su opciones. 

Basado en la documentación de https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/wiki/Menu-Configuration#the-route-attribute. 
yo puedo pasar un parametros al menú, pero aqui está de forma estática o fija 
[
    'text'  => 'Profile',
    'route' => ['admin.profile', ['userID' => '673']],
    'icon'  => 'fas fa-fw fa-user',
]
```

No encuentro como pasar el id dinamicamente al \config\adminlte.php para que lo reciba el menu.

```
Espero que puedan orientarme, un gran saludo.
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer lo siguiente. Quita del adminlte.php el item.
Lo vamos a crear desde el EventServiceProvider. Por tanto, vas a Providers>EventServiceProvider.php
En mi caso yo quiero obtener los datos de un paciente que está relacionado con la tablas usuarios. En realidad, lo que quiero es que el usuario que esté registrado vea sus datos.
Escribimos:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\Events\BuildingMenu;
use App\Models\Paciente;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

en tu caso el modelo que vayas a utilizar.
[image: codigo]

Si deseas incluir el item en algún lugar determinado del menú puedes usar AddAfter, o AddBefore. Puedes ver como en la documentación de [AdminLTE](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/wiki/Menu-Configuration#menu-configuration-at-runtime)
Al finalizar recuerda borrar la cache con
php artisan config:cache
para que refresque el menú lateral

Comment: El código completo de tu respuesta debe ir como texto por favor